# Why does my Swan 2070B washing machine make loud banging sounds?

Tags: washing-machine, noise

Machine has a loud banging noise that reverberates through the floor,gets louder and faster the faster the spin. I've checked the bearings for play, the balance weights for tightness or cracks, replaced the two shock absorbers underneath, looked for any broken support springs, and attempted to look for any trapped socks etc, by shining a torch through the holes in the inner drum, removed and cleaned the filter, if you can call it that. But everything seems OK. The machine stays steady as a rock, there's hardly any drum wobble, all seems fine and steady apart from this loud thumping noise as it spins. Everything seems to point to a trapped item in the drum, but I can't see inside properly without a complete strip down, which could end up being for nothing.      Is there an easier way to look inside the drum and remove any foreign objects? Is it possible to get in through soap dispenser, or at the top of the drum somewhere as in some other models? Or can you suggest some other problem I've not yet checked.

Comment: Is this a new washer? If so, were the shipping bolts removed?

Answer (score 1):

I've had two washers fail after many years of service due to structural failure. The first one, a front loader, failed because the outer drum cylinder that holds the bearings broke away from the outer drum, the welds failed.  The second one, a top loader, failed  because the vertical shaft for the inner drum partially broke away from the inner drum. Both worked until spinning under load. Neither one was worth trying to fix due to a lot of rust on the metal parts.